Clicking a button with Selenium and Python until no longer exists
I'm trying to scrape this site:https://www.vertexconnects.com/find-atc
I can't seem to get the while loop to continue to click the "Load More" button after you put in any zipcode. The code seems to be failing on the locations line, getting each of the location results, with this error
   raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message: 

Code below:
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options = options)
action = ActionChains(driver)

driver.get("https://www.vertexconnects.com/find-atc")
driver.maximize_window()
wait = WebDriverWait(driver,5)
# Use below line only if you are getting the Accept/Reject cookies pop-up
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//button[contains(.,'Accept All')]"))).click()

location_textbox = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID,"location-search-input")))
action.move_to_element(location_textbox).click().send_keys("10001").perform()
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CLASS_NAME, "atc-finder-button"))).click()

while True:
    try:
        wait.until(EC_element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "loadMore"))).click()
    except:
        break

print("done")

locations = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='location-result']")))

for location in locations:
    name = location.find_element(By.TAG_NAME, "h4").text()
    address = location.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "address atc-finder-hospital-address").text()
    phone_num = location.find_element(By.TAG_Name, "a").text
    print(name, address, phone_num)


have a look at this.
also all the locations/details are available in the page's html (LOC_CONFIGURATION). you can easily get them using requests and beautifulsoup.

Thank you for the help. I didn't realize all of the details were in the html. To grab LOC_CONFIGURATION using beautiful soup would you use soup.find_all('script') and then select the specific one? Or is there a better way to search for LOC_CONFIGURATION? It's been a while since i used BS

I guess you could use soup.body.select_one('#block-atcmapblock > script:first-child'), then extract the  LOC_CONFIGURATION variable using regex or string manipulation.

Issues in your code:

Fact that your while loop is not effectively clicking the Load More button was due to below:
1a. In the below code, there is syntax error. It should be EC. and not EC_
wait.until(EC_element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "loadMore"))).click()

1b. Selenium is not able to locate the Load More button with EC.element_to_be_clickable. Change it to EC.presence_of_element_located

In below code, it should be .text at the end
name = location.find_element(By.TAG_NAME, "h4").text()
address = location.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "address atc-finder-hospital-address").text()


Below locator strategy is incorrect. You can't use CLASS_NAME when there are multiple classes. FYI, address is one class and atc-finder-hospital-address is another.
By.CLASS_NAME, "address atc-finder-hospital-address"


If you notice the webpage, not every hospital has a phone number. So below line for code will fail when there is no <a> tag found
phone_num = location.find_element(By.TAG_Name, "a").text



Here is the refactored code:
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options = options)

driver.get("https://www.vertexconnects.com/find-atc")
driver.maximize_window()
wait = WebDriverWait(driver,10)
# Use below line only if you are getting the Accept/Reject cookies pop-up
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//button[contains(.,'Accept All')]"))).click()

wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID,"location-search-input"))).send_keys("10001")
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CLASS_NAME, "atc-finder-button"))).click()

while True:
    try:
        wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "loadMore"))).click()
        time.sleep(3)
    except:
        break

print("done")

locations = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='location-result']")))

for location in locations:
    name = location.find_element(By.TAG_NAME, "h4").text
    address = location.find_element(By.XPATH, "//div[@class='address atc-finder-hospital-address']").text
    phone_num = location.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, "a")
    if len(phone_num)>0:
        print(name, address, phone_num[0].text)
    else:
        print(name, address)

Console output:
done
Cohen Children's Medical Center 269-01 76th Avenue, New Hyde Park, NY 11040, US
Children’s Hospital of Philadelphia 269-01 76th Avenue, New Hyde Park, NY 11040, US (267) 601-3461
Dana-Farber Brigham Cancer Center 269-01 76th Avenue, New Hyde Park, NY 11040, US (877) 442-3324
Massachusetts General Hospital 269-01 76th Avenue, New Hyde Park, NY 11040, US (617) 643-9042
Boston Medical Center 269-01 76th Avenue, New Hyde Park, NY 11040, US (617) 638-8130
Children's National Hospital 269-01 76th Avenue, New Hyde Park, NY 11040, US (202) 476-5367
CLEVELAND CLINIC 269-01 76th Avenue, New Hyde Park, NY 11040, US (216) 444-5517
Nationwide Children's Hospital 269-01 76th Avenue, New Hyde Park, NY 11040, US (614) 722-6425 Option 6
Ohio State University Wexner Medical Center 269-01 76th Avenue, New Hyde Park, NY 11040, US (614) 293-3153
Cincinnati Children's Hospital Medical Center 269-01 76th Avenue, New Hyde Park, NY 11040, US (513) 517-2234
University of Chicago 269-01 76th Avenue, New Hyde Park, NY 11040, US (773) 702-6808
Northwestern Memorial Hospital 269-01 76th Avenue, New Hyde Park, NY 11040, US (312) 695-0990
The Children’s Hospital At Tristar Centennial 269-01 76th Avenue, New Hyde Park, NY 11040, US
Children's Hospital of New Orleans 269-01 76th Avenue, New Hyde Park, NY 11040, US
Medical City Dallas Hospital 269-01 76th Avenue, New Hyde Park, NY 11040, US
Methodist Hospital 269-01 76th Avenue, New Hyde Park, NY 11040, US
City of Hope National Medical Center 269-01 76th Avenue, New Hyde Park, NY 11040, US (800) 826-4673 genetherapy@coh.org
Children's Hospital of Orange County (CHOC) 269-01 76th Avenue, New Hyde Park, NY 11040, US

Process finished with exit code 0

